# How can I create a visual folder map of our Google Drive?

Tags: display

I am trying to create a visual map/directory of our Google Drive (like the attached image) so that users can easily find documents.  To sit and type everything out would take too much time...I can make the images into bullets, but I just need the bullet list already formatted.  Basically, how it already looks in Windows, but with every folder showing, expanded and showing its contents. I created an example if you would like a visual of what I am trying to achieve...

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding!!! It won't let me attach it; can I email it to you?

Comment: http://imgur.com/iX9WiH6

Comment: @Steven - is there a way to get more feedback?  Or should I assume that no one can help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [freeMIND](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and the google drive application to generate a map of the contents of google drive

1. I installed Drive on my pc, in this way I can see all folders as an extension of my HDD.
   __.
2. I installed FreeMIND and you can go in to File/Import/Folder Structure...
3. Select you Drive folder as appears on your Computer/.. .GoogleDriveFolder/..